# open the location of a folder from the output of where command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, pipe

How can I use `where` *command* to find the location of a executable and then open the location of it using `explorer` *command* in windows command tool without the advanced *powershell*.

This command is not working.
niether of the command works and i have tried quite a few combinations:

`where sftp | explorer`

`where sftp | explorer<&1`

`where sftp >&1 | explorer<&1`

i have tried other handles as well and getting an error for 3rd trial

`The handle could not be duplicate
during redirection of handle 1.`

The other 2 trials opens default explorer location.

Comment: you probably should change the tag window to windows, since you are on windows right?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly does seem odd that piping the output of `where` doesn't work as you'd expect--it didn't work for me, either.  But here's a slightly more complicated approach to get what you want.  Assuming your `where sftp` syntax actually returns the file you're referencing, this should work:

```
for /f %%A in ('where sftp') do explorer %%~dpA
```

This loops through each line of the output of the `where` command and runs explorer for each result.  See `for /?` for more information.

Comment: I think you meant to say **for /f %%A in ('where sftp') do explorer %%~dpA** (with the tilde ~)

Comment: Yes.  That's what I meant.  Fixed now. :)